# Why do I get 3 lines of log at Monitor.exe when using Debug.Log in Unity?

Tags: android, unity, debugging

- I'm debugging a real device.
- In a `GUILayer.Button` I've put a single `Debug.Log()` message, like in this code

Code:

```
if( GUILayout.Button( "Click to Test." ) )
{
    Debug.Log( "XAVI Clicked!" );
}
```

- But in `monitor.exe` I get 3 lines, like the following ones:

[image]

- To filter out messy messages from other applications, my filter is "tag:unity".
- The APK is compiled with `Development Build` unchecked.

**Problem:**

I expected to see only one log line, with the text `XAVI Clicked!` but I also got a blank line and a line referencing a filename that I don't know what is it.

Those 2 lines are a consequence of "logging", not a consequence of "clicking the button", as if I remove my log sentence, then I do not receive my log but also I don't receive those phantom two lines (zero log lines then).

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way I get rid of those lines I don't want to see?
2. Is there any way I can create my own filtering tag inside the Unity?
3. How do you handle if you want to see exclusively your logs but not "extra logs" placed by the system?
4. Is there any reason that I should keep watching those lines? Are they carrying meaningful intormation? What do they tell to me that is relevant to me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Those other lines are your callstack.  It's just how Unity does things -- as far as I know you can't change it.

If you want to filter them out, what you can likely do is add a prefix to your own debug logs and filter off of that instead of just relying on the tags.